# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'present' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

> ActionSheetCmp.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'present'
>   of undefined

my code :

```
 onManageIngredients() {
      const actionSheet = this.actionSheetController.create ({
        title: 'waht do you want to do?',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Add Ingredient',
            handler: () => {
              this.createNewIngredientAlert().present();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `this.createNewIngredientAlert()` is probably returning `undefined` or anything at all.

(just a guess)I think, here you tried calling a `(alert)AlertController` based on callback, try returning `AlertController` instance in `this.createNewIngredientAlert()` method